# C function based on pointer to const

Tags: c, pointers, pic

I have developed code for PIC and I am happy with it.
The problem is that my variables are putter into RAM and it is almost full.

I have tried with const in front of array of data, but I failed with later function based on pointer to const array.

Could somebody show me how to define that pointer?

That is what I have now:

```
#define type     unsigned int8
#define memType  const type
memType n_006 = 2;
type l_006[n_006]={0x03, 0xFF};
```

Function:

```
void writeLine(type adress, type *send, int8 numS)
{
   int8 i = 0;
   i2c_start();
   i2c_write(adress);  
   for(i = 0; i < numS; i++)
   {
      int8 toSend = send[i];
      i2c_write(toSend);
   }
   i2c_stop();
}
```

And in main:

```
 writeLine(a1, &l_006[0], n_006);
```

Main goal is to have data saved in ROM, what I guess could be doned by const in front, but I really failed to do it correctly.

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: Failed how? Compiler error? Runtime error? Be specific.

Comment: Why are you using `#define` instead of `typedef`

Comment: Some PIC compilers oblige `const` data to be transferred to non-`const` with select functions like `memcpy()`.  Post code that failed and describe how it failed.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler may support extra specifiers that explicitly assign storage for globals (EEPROM, etc.).

Also it is much better to use `typedef`'s instead of macro.

```
typedef unsigned int8 type, *ptype;
typedef const type memType;
memType n_006 = 2;
type l_006[n_006]={0x03, 0xFF};
```

Also you may get rid of the `n_006` at all, just use well-known `sizeof` trick:

```
writeLine(a1, l_006, sizeof l_006 / sizeof l_006[0]);
```

Comment: While typedef over macro is certainly preferred, it should not be source of OP's problem. Also, hiding a pointer type behind typedef is always ugly.

Comment: It does not work.
On the line:
 typedef const type memType;
I have an error "Expecting an ="

Comment: @user694733 "... hiding a pointer type behind typedef is always ugly ..." IMO it is a matter of taste.

Comment: Not really a _matter of taste_ when you develop libs and users are not aware they are passing triple or more pointer to some functions, for example. Not the case here with embedded app.

Comment: Typedef'd pointers also start to fall apart when you write `const` and `volatile` -correct code, as each requires their own typedef. And even more if you use additional type qualifiers provided by the compiler, as is often case in the embedded world.

Comment: @user694733  @LPs Reasonable points. And what about `typedef`-ed function pointers? AFAIK it is a common practice to `typedef` them because of much better readability.

Comment: typedefs with qualifiers can sometimes lead to linker errors.  On some compilers (I can't remember which ones offhand), when you create a signature of __const int__, they change it to __int const__ but when you typedef, it doesn't change the signature.  Everything goes through until you try to link and then it all falls apart.

Answer (score 0):

As serhio says, check your special compiler specifiers.  For instance on the XC8 compiler (which doesn't have int8, so I have to use char)

```
const unsigned char ylist[] = { 0x03, 0xFF };
```

Generates

```
stringdir:  
    movlw   high stringdir
    movwf   10
    movf    4,w
    incf    4,f
    addwf   2,f
__stringbase:   
    retlw   0
__end_of__stringtab:    
_ylist: 
    retlw   3
    retlw   255
__end_of_ylist;
```

But using the keyword eeprom instead of const

```
eeprom unsigned char ylist[] = { 0x03, 0xFF };
```

Generates

```
_ylist: 
;initializer for _ylist
    db  3
    db  255
```

It uses half the amount of space and doesn't have the string conversion routine.  It probably runs a lot faster too.

Answer (score 0):

I use CCS C Compiler

I used:

```
#define type     unsigned int8
#define memType  const type
#define tabType  rom type
```

and it worked

SOLVED